# Customizing headers and binding to properties work but it also display original

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I created a simple LINQ to populate a `<DataGrid Name="CarsGrid">` from a SQL Server database

```
.Select(ims => new
               {
                   ims.cars.ModelId,
                   ims.cars.colorId,
                   ims.cars.typeId,
               }
.DefaultIfEmpty().ToList();

CarsGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

This works, 3 columns are displayed (`ModelId`, `colorId` and `typeId`).

Then I tried to customize the grid as follows:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="My Model ID" Width="90" Binding="{Binding  ModelId}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="My Color ID" Width="90" Binding="{Binding  colorId}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="My Type ID" Width="90" Binding="{Binding  typeId}" />
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Now, when I run the application, the grid displays 6 columns ("My Model ID" and "ModelId", "My Color ID" and "colorId"..etc)

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Set AutoGenerateColumns to false.